# Count matching entries in a database row unless the row is empty

Tags: sql, database, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

Count the consecutive (specific) matching entrys in a row but start from scratch if something else is in between.

My Idea is to look how many login attempts someone has made in a timeframe (in my case 15 minutes) and act accordingly. For example (simplified table):

```
Row: User_id | Loginstatus | Timestamp
     5           Attempt        most recent 
     5           Attempt        .
     5           Logoff         .
     5           Login          .
     5           Attempt        .
     5           Attempt        .
     5           Attempt        . 
     5           Attempt        .
     5           Logoff         .
     5           Login          .
     5           Logoff         . 
     5           Login          .
```

My select should now produce: 2

What I got so far:

```
select count(Loginstatus) Result  from Userlog
where User_Id = 5
and Loginstatus = 'ATTEMPT'
and Timestamp > Systimestamp - Interval '15' Minute;
```

but this counts all the Attempts unfortunately. I am happy for any help and thank you in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the difference of row numbers to identify adjacent sequences:

```
select user_id, count(*) as num_consecutive
from (select ul.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as seqnum_u,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, loginstatus order by timestamp) as seqnum_us

      from Userlog ul
      where User_Id = 5 and Timestamp > Systimestamp - Interval '15' Minute;
     ) ul
where Loginstatus = 'ATTEMPT'
group by user_id, (seqnum_u - seqnum_us);
```

If you want one value, you can add:

```
order by num_consecutive desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much kind sir :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql):

```
SELECT [LoginStatus]=MAX(Loginstatus), [Count]=count(Loginstatus) 
FROM Userlog
WHERE User_Id = 5
AND Loginstatus = 'ATTEMPT'
AND Timestamp > Systimestamp - Interval '15' Minute;
GROUP BY (Loginstatus)
```